# Definition of Successor function in Peano Axioms

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

Dedekind-Peano axioms characterize (in first-order logic) the natural numbers ($\mathbb{N}$) as follows:

> A1. $0 \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> A2. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: n' \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> A3. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: n' \not= 0$.
>
> A4. $\forall n,m \in \mathbb{N}: n' = m' \rightarrow n = m$.
>
> A5. $[(0) \land \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \varphi(n) \rightarrow \varphi(S(n))] \rightarrow \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \varphi(n)$.†

My question is about the implicit definition of the successor function $(\cdot)'$. It seems to me that we need to define it (which means, at least, that we need to specify its domain and codomain) in order for A1-5 to be meaningful. But can we even say so little as that
it is a mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ when A1-A5 are what define $\mathbb{N}$?  Is there not a circularity there? If 'no', might it be that $(\cdot)'$ is given all of its relevant meaning by A1-A5?

---

† A5 is not really an axiom but a schema for generating an infinity of actual axioms for each $\phi$.

Comment: If you allow quantifying over subsets of $N$, you could turn A5 into an axiom: $\forall P\subset N: [0\in P \land \forall x\in P: x'\in P\implies \forall x\in N: x\in P]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line 2 is equivalent to $': N\to N$.

It's would be a little more clear if you used the notation $S: N\to N$. Then $n'$ becomes $S(n)$.

Comment: Of course! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

As said by Dan, Axiom 2 says that the *successor* $S$ is a *mapping* from $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{N}$.

Axiom 4 says that it is *injective*, i.e. two different numbers cannot have the same successor.

But you must take into account that the "proper" context for the translation of the original *Dedekind-Peano axioms* must be second-order logic.

If we are working with first-order logic, things are slightly different.

See **S.C.Kleene**, *Mathematical Logic* (1967, Dover reprint), pag.209 :

> " Axiom 14 [i.e. $ a' = b' \rightarrow a = b$] and Axiom 15 [i.e. $\lnot a = 0$] and Axiom Schema 13 [i.e. f-o induction schema] formalize the third, fourth and fifth of Peano's list of five axioms for the natural numbers, 1889. Peano's first axiom, that $0$ is a natural number, and his second axiom, that if $n$ is a natural number so is $n+1$, are taken care of instead by the formation rules [of the f-o language] which make $0$ a term and whenever $r$ is a term make $(r)'$ a term, since all the terms in the system are interpreted as expressing natural numbers."

Comment: The fourth axiom says it's an injective relation, not that it's a function.

Answer (score 1):

In the definition of an interpretation of first-order logic we require that if $M$ is an interpretation to a language, and $F$ is an $n$-ary symbol function, then the interpretation $F^M$ is a function from $M^n$ to $M$.

The syntax does not concern itself with such issues, and axioms are part of the syntax, rather than the semantics.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. (Also, thanks for fixing the tags; I'll eventually figure out how to not make more work for you.)